# Homomorphism and kernel of p-adic integers

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, group-homomorphism

> Let $U=\mathbb{Z}^{\ast}_p$ be the group of p-adic units. For every $n\geq 1$ put $U_n=1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$.
>   This is the kernel of the homomorphism $\varepsilon_n:U\to (\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^{\ast}$, $\varepsilon_n(x)=x_n$

I want to show, that

1) $\varepsilon_n$ is indeed a homomorphism and

2) that the kernel is given by $1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$

Ad 1)

Let $x,y\in U$, then $\varepsilon(xy)=x_ny_n$ since the multiplication in $\mathbb{Z}_p^\ast$ works "by components". From there we proceed: $x_ny_n=\varepsilon_n(x)\varepsilon_n(y)$ and are done.

So $\varepsilon_n$ is indeed a homomorphism.

Ad 2)

$\ker(\varepsilon_n)=\{x\in U|~x_n\equiv 1\mod p^n\}=1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$

Is this really that easy, or do I have to be more precise? Espacially for 2).
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What definition of $\mathbb{Z}_p^*$ are you using? In particular, what are the "components" in there?

Comment: We defined $\mathbb{Z}_p$ as the projective limit of the system $(A_n,\phi_n)$, where $A_n=\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\phi_n: A_n\to A_{n-1}$. Therefore an element of $x\in\mathbb{Z}_p$  is a sequence $x=(\dotso, x_n,\dotso, x_1)$, where $x_n\in A_n$. Addition and multiplication is defined "coordinate by coordinate", which i probably messed up by refering to "components". Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. I think your proofs are correct then. Maybe one should add to 1) that the map is well-defined (i.e., $x_n$ is really a unit in $\mathbb{Z}/p^n \mathbb{Z}$ for $x \in \mathbb{Z}_p^*$). And in 2), one might have to give an extra argument for the second equality.

Comment: Yes, the 2nd equality is what I think a little bit odd. Why do we get $1+p^n\mathbb{Z}_p$? I expected $1+p^n\mathbb{Z}$, since $\varepsilon_n$ maps onto $(\mathbb{Z}/p^n\mathbb{Z})^\ast$

Comment: But the kernel is a subset of $U$. And the set should actually be $\{x\in U|~\varepsilon_n (x_n)\equiv 1\mod p^n \}$. Then the subtle bit is to show that that is indeed the same as the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_p$ that are congruent to $1$ mod $p^n$, for which one first has to clarify what it means for $(..., x_n, ..., x_1)$ to be congruent to "1" -- that is, $(..., \bar 1, ..., \bar 1)$ -- modulo $p^n$ (that is, mod $(..., \bar {p^n}, ..., \bar {p^n})$).

Comment: Should it not be $(\dotso, [1+p^n],\dotso, [1+p^n])$ to get that it is congruent to $1$ mod $p^n$?

Comment: Sorry, my last comment is incorrect, the set after the first equality is as you describe it in the OP. The rest should be correct though, and yes, it is also the same as in your last comment, but one might still fill in details why that is all the same.

Comment: Which detail do I miss out?